# Java String to String[] of possible prefixes

Tags: java, string, prefix

I would like to create an array of prefixes to iterate through from a string.

This is to create some tests where the options are matched using `String.startsWith`

For example `"start"` would become `{ "s", "st", "sta", "star", "start" }`

Comment: At this point I am putting it through by hand, as there aren't that many. But I have made a mistake once, so was wondering if there was some nice library that would do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code,

```
     String str = "start";

     String strArray[] = new String [str.length()]; 

     for (int i=0 ; i< str.length() ; i++)
     {
        strArray[i] = str.substring(0,i+1);
        System.out.println("strArray["+i+"] = " +strArray[i]  );
     }
```

**Output:**

```
strArray[0] = s
strArray[1] = st
strArray[2] = sta
strArray[3] = star
strArray[4] = start
```

Comment: @Unihedron: Thank you! Have changed

Comment: @Unihedron: I tried the code in my local eclipse and posted the compiled version with output. Thank you again!

Comment: you should let the guy work a little before you show the code , BTW appreciate ur effort

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri': Thank you! But may be you can consider showing your appreciation by an upvote...!!

Comment: happy ?? :) :) , but I still think , one should let the person try first .